# Ignore html,css and other code in textarea

Tags: jquery, html

Here is an example:

I write html code inside of textarea, then I swap its content with one of the div elements to see live changes (jquery). Happens vise versa, from div to textarea and back. There are two textareas: one for html another for css. Textarea for css is swapped with one of the  elements. Sounds funny? =)

Long story short: when it comes to the point where I need to write `<textarea>...</textarea>` inside of html's textarea or write "textarea { font-style: bold; }" inside of css's textarea - THIS CODING is getting applied to my html and css textareas creating mess on swap.

How do I make textarea ignore what is inside of it and treat all content as text?

Swapping is done this way (actually it's much more complicated, but idea is the same):

```
var html = $('.content').html();
$('.editors').append("<textarea class='editorhtml' spellcheck='false'>"+html+"</textarea>"); // .editors is outside of .content

//and

$('.content').html($('.editorhtml').val());
$('.editorhtml').remove();
```

Wow! That was hard to explain. Are you confused?

Comment: _That was hard to explain_ **and hard to understand** What about a **JSFiddle**?

Comment: you are right there. I am confused. If you post a link, we could see live

Comment: You question is very nice, but an example will be more useful.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rtPYG/ - Works good? Now put "<textarea></textarea>" in the textarea, save and edit again. Ending tag is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `val()`to set the content of the textarea instead of just concatenating the strings to set the current content as default value of the textarea:

```
var html = $('.content').html();
$("<textarea class='editorhtml' spellcheck='false'>").val(html).appendTo($('.editors'));
```

You'll find an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/9SbGt/

Comment: I don't need it as text in .content, I want it to be an actual html.

Comment: Sorry, I got your question wrong. Your fiddle really helps. See my edited answer

Comment: Good one! This is for html. What to do with css where for example textarea { font-style: bold; } is getting applied to editorhtml? I understand that bold is becoming a part of document and applies to all textareas. Are there any workarounds? Thanks.

Comment: With CSS, things are not so simple, as you cannot exclude a certain textarea from the css-rules that are applied to the rest of the document. The most reliable method would be to use iframes as Christoph suggested. If this is not an option, you could use jQuery's .css() on the textarea to set all the relevant style-attributes to defined values to overwrite rules that the user might have set.

Answer (score 0):

Use "scoped" style-declaration (bad browsersupport) or iframes!

Comment: It's not only about me. Some people have access to the site and they could mess with styles too. How about <textarea></textarea> tag inside of textarea? iframes are far away from html5+jquery!

Comment: why are iframes far away from html5??? I really don't understand that. check out jsfiddle, they use Iframes too, which are perfect for encapsulating your styles.

Comment: Specific structure wont allow to use iframes. Even if I try, it would take lots of hours to redo everything. How about some jquery trick where textarea element will ignore all other styles except specified?

Comment: read http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know and if you have problems, ask again;) I'm pretty sure, this will answer your question. (Overview: make your styles so important, that they can't be overridden)

Comment: Yeah yeah, gimme more sh.t. I already found some workaround for it: swap functions as parser for css textarea, if it finds any overwrites to textarea it wont swap and alert an error. =)